# Remote debugging java - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to debug a java program on my remote computer, which the following command:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y  suspend=y -jar Test.jar
```

When I try remote debugging with eclipse on my local computer, I see this error on the remote computer:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
Error: Could not find or load main class suspend=y
```

I don't understand since I do have a main class in the program.

P/S: I also have the same error when trying to run the jar file by

```
java Test.jar
```

The project is built with Eclipse IDE.

Can someone show me where I did wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y  suspend=y -jar Test.jar
```

You're missing a `,` between `server=y` and `suspend=y`. Even the introduction of a space in the parameters can confuse the VM.

This is the right syntax.

`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9991,server=y,suspend=n -jar my.jar`

If your jar has the right main class attribute it should work correctly.